# Perform numpy product over non-zero elements of a row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2d array `r`. What I want to do is to take the product of each row (excluding the zero elements in that row). For example if I have:

```
r = [[1 2 0 3 4],
     [0 2 5 0 1],
     [1 2 3 4 0]]
```

Then what I want is to have another 2d array `result` such that:

```
result = [[24],
          [10],
          [24]]
```

How can I achieve this using numpy.prod?

Comment: You could do something like: `np.prod(r + (r==0), axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
np.prod(r, axis = 1, where = r > 0, keepdims = True)
```

Output:

```
array([[24],                                                                                                                   
[10],                                                                                                                   
[24]])
```